# Переключение активного состояния кнопок при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день.
Не получается реализовать переключение кнопок. 
У меня есть две кнопки. При нажатии на верхнюю ей должен добавлять класс .active, при нажатии на нижнюю к нижней добавляться класс .active, с верхней убираться.

Код html:

```
<div class="sorting-order">
 <div class="icon-play3 sort-parameter">
 </div>
 <div class="icon-play3 sort-parameter">
 </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.sort-parameter').click( function() {
 $(".sort-parameter").toggleClass("active");
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку нужно сначала удалить класс `.active` у всех кнопок, а потом добавлять его нажимаемой кнопке:

```js
$('.sort-parameter').click(function() {
  $('.sort-parameter').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
.sort-parameter {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.sort-parameter.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sorting-order">
  <div class="icon-play3 sort-parameter">
  </div>
  <div class="icon-play3 sort-parameter">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Kate пожалуйста:)

Answer (score 1):

Вы забили использовать $(this) - применять именно к тому элементу, на котором было собитие. + в начале надо удалить класс active у всех кнопок(если их вдруг будет много) тогда подойдет $('.sort-parameter') - уберет актив со всех кнопок.
В вашем случае получалось, что вы добавляли класс всем элементам которых нашел jquery с классом sort-parameter, а надо на кликнутом - $(this).

```js
$('.sort-parameter').click( function() {
  $('.sort-parameter').removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sorting-order">
 <div class="icon-play3 sort-parameter">
    test-up
 </div>
 <div class="icon-play3 sort-parameter">
    test-down
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!